# can ping other machines but other machines can not ping me

Tags: vmware, networking

Inside the Virtual Machine ,running Ubuntu, I can ping outside machines and can even connect to the internet, but outside machines can not ping me except my host Windows machine,

The VMware Image use bridge mode and The IP of the Ubuntu is get from DHCP.

What could be catchy here and how to diagnose it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can access your machine through other ways. Ubuntu has ping switched off sometimes, try and switch it back on using this:

In Ubuntu ping can be enabled by adding following line to your /etc/init.d/networking script.

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
```

This adds to ability to be pinged using ICMP calls. Check out what your current settings are by using cat on /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all

Comment: What are the determining factors for whether pingability is switched off?